# How to use Javascript eventlistener to call functions which draw dc.js charts/graphs, etc?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have different html buttons, which call different sets of DC.js graphs/charts/numbers, etc., but at the moment, I don't know how to add an eventlistener to trigger them.

The below code is two of the buttons: all-seasons and s_06. I need to be able to switch between them, by simply clicking the buttons, without having to physically hardcode them in, and by "hardcode" I mean using `//` to block out the one I don't want and then reload the page!

I have `show_all_info` running on page load, as you can see below.

```
show_all_info(ndx);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    document.getElementById("all-seasons").addEventListener("click", show_all_info);
    document.getElementById("s_06").addEventListener("click", show_06_info);
});
```

At the moment, `show_all_info(ndx)` is loading fine and as it should, but then nothing happens when I click the s_06 button.

```
function show_all_info(ndx) {
  show_all_wins_pie(ndx);
  show_all_poles_pie(ndx);
  show_all_fast_laps_pie(ndx);
  show_all_constructor_points(ndx);
}

function show_06_info(ndx) {
  show_wins_pie(ndx, "06");
  show_poles_pie(ndx, "06");
  show_fast_laps_pie(ndx, "06");
  show_points(ndx, "06");
  show_driver_world_champ_chart(ndx, "06", "Fernando Alonso");
  // etc.
}
```

#### Version 1: re-initialize the charts

Here's the actual code (I will paste only 1 pie from each):

```
function show_all_wins_pie(ndx) {
  var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("win_car"));
  var group = dim.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) {
      p.count++;
      if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
        p.match++;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
      return p;
    },
    function(p, v) {
      p.count--;
      if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
        p.match--;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
      return p;
    },
    function() {
      return { count: 0, match: 0 };
    }
  );

  dc.pieChart("#wins-pie")
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    .radius(100)
    .innerRadius(40)
    .dimension(dim)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
      if(d.value.count > 0) {
        return d.value.match;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })
    .group(group)
    .transitionDuration(1000);
}
function show_wins_pie(ndx, season) {
  var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("win_car"));
  var group = dim.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) {
      if(v.season == season) {
        p.count++;
        if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
          p.match++;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
      return p;
    },
    function(p, v) {
      if(v.season == season) {
        p.count--;
        if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
          p.match--;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
      return p;
    },
    function() {
      return { count: 0, match: 0 };
    }
  );

  dc.pieChart("#wins-pie")
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    .radius(100)
    .innerRadius(40)
    .dimension(dim)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
      if(d.value.count > 0) {
        return d.value.match;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })
    .group(group)
    .transitionDuration(1000);
}
```

#### Version 2: only render the first time

After addressing Gordon's answer and comments below, I ended up with the following, but the season buttons still don't do anything:

```
function show_all_wins_pie(ndx) {
  var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("win_car"));
  var group = dim.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) {
      p.count++;
      if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
        p.match++;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
      return p;
    },
    function(p, v) {
      p.count--;
      if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
        p.match--;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
      return p;
    },
    function() {
      return { count: 0, match: 0 };
    }
  );

  if(allWinsPie) {
    allWinsPie.redraw();
  } else {
    allWinsPie = dc.pieChart("#wins-pie");
  allWinsPie
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    .radius(100)
    .innerRadius(40)
    .dimension(dim)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
      if(d.value.count > 0) {
        return d.value.match;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })
    .group(group)
    .transitionDuration(1000);

  allWinsPie.render();
  }
}
function show_wins_pie(ndx, season) {
  var dim = ndx.dimension(dc.pluck("win_car"));
  var group = dim.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) {
      if(v.season == season) {
        p.count++;
        if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
          p.match++;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
      return p;
    },
    function(p, v) {
      if(v.season == season) {
        p.count--;
        if(v.win_car != "N/A") {
          p.match--;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
      return p;
    },
    function() {
      return { count: 0, match: 0 };
    }
  );

  if(winsPie) {
    winsPie.redraw();
  } else {
    winsPie = dc.pieChart("#wins-pie")
  winsPie
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    .radius(100)
    .innerRadius(40)
    .dimension(dim)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
      if(d.value.count > 0) {
        return d.value.match;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })
    .group(group)
    .transitionDuration(1000);

  winsPie.render();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think the problem is in this code. This is just the clicks and I don't see anything wrong here (although personally I would use D3 for this, so maybe I'm missing something). The question is: why doesn't `show_06_info` replace the charts that were initialized by `show_all_info`. And I don't think we can help you figure that out without seeing those functions.

Comment: @Gordon , thanks for your reply. I will paste the functions below:

function show_all_info(ndx) {
  show_all_wins_pie(ndx);
  show_all_poles_pie(ndx);
  show_all_fast_laps_pie(ndx);
  show_all_constructor_points(ndx);
  dc.renderAll();
}

function show_06_info(ndx) {
  show_wins_pie(ndx, "2006");
  show_poles_pie(ndx, "2006");
  show_fast_laps_pie(ndx, "2006");
  show_points(ndx, "2006");
  dc.renderAll();
}

Comment: That's still not enough code to diagnose the problem. If it's not possible to create a self contained example (e.g. a jsfiddle) then at least consider what a person who doesn't know what you're working on would need to know in order to understand the problem.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question and adding the code from your comment, as well as a sample of a couple of the functions called by the code in your comment. (That said, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is always better... but it does take some work and practice.)

Comment: @Gordon , thanks for the tips. I'm new to this so that helps. I have edited the question to include some actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually okay to change a bunch of parameters and re-render dc.js charts. If you're just changing the data, you can redraw instead of rendering - that way you get transitions.

We've had a conversation in the comments, and I have edited it into your question and my answer.

#### version 1: don't re-construct charts

In the first version you attempted to re-*construct* the charts by calling the chart constructor (`dc.pieChart`, `dc.barChart`). The new chart instance may not be able to steal the DOM from the last one.

I don't have an example I can easily test, but I think that if you make sure the charts are only initialized once, that should get things working:

```
// global (top) level
let stackedChart, pie;
// ...
function show_all_constructor_points(ndx) {
// ...
  if(!stackedChart)
    stackedChart = dc.barChart("#all-constructor-points");
  // as before, but don't re-construct:
  stackedChart
    .width(width)
    .height(400)
  // ...

function show_wins_pie(ndx, season) {
  // ...
  if(!pie)
    pie = dc.pieChart("#wins-pie")
  pie
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    .radius(100)
```

In the comments, I mentioned that you should render only the first time, and then redraw whenever the data or filters change.

#### version 2: set the data before redrawing

When you first initialize the chart and set all its parameters, you need to **render** the chart in order to create the SVG elements.

Later on, when you change the data, you want to **redraw** the chart so that it will animate from the old data to the new data. (This works with many but not all chart parameters too.)

In version 2 of your code, the only problem should be (hopefully) that you need to set the new data before you redraw.

So instead of

```
  if(winsPie) {
    winsPie.redraw();
  } else {
    winsPie = dc.pieChart("#wins-pie")
  winsPie
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    .radius(100)
    .innerRadius(40)
    .dimension(dim)
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {
      if(d.value.count > 0) {
        return d.value.match;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    })
    .group(group)
    .transitionDuration(1000);

  winsPie.render();
```

This ought to do the trick:

```
  if(winsPie) {
    winsPie
      .group(group)
      .dimension(dim)
      .redraw();
  } else {
    winsPie = dc.pieChart("#wins-pie")
    winsPie
      .height(200)
      .width(200)
      .radius(100)
      .innerRadius(40)
      .dimension(dim)
      .valueAccessor(function(d) {
        if(d.value.count > 0) {
          return d.value.match;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      })
      .group(group)
      .transitionDuration(1000)
      .render();
  }
```

#### version 3: event handlers activated and not stomping eachother

Looking at your repo, I found a few problems:

1. As you guessed, the event handlers in the two files were interfering with each other. One way to avoid this is by using d3's [`.on()` with a namespace](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v1.4.0/README.md#selection_on)
2. Also `DOMContentLoaded` didn't fire for me, but you don't need it there because you are already waiting for the data, which will take longer.
3. Also, your event handlers take `ndx`, so you need to wrap them in some sort of function that provides them that
4. Finally, you'll need to dispose of the old dimensions when they are no longer needed, since crossfilter only supports 32 (and these objects are heavy weight).
5. One little glitch: if you let anchor clicks trigger the default handler, the page will scroll to the top when they are clicked. `event.preventDefault` is the solution here.

script.js event handlers:

```
function wrap_handler(h) { // #3
    return function() {
        d3.event.preventDefault(); // #5
        h(ndx);
    };
}

document.getElementById("all-seasons").addEventListener("click", show_all_info);
d3.select("#s-06").on('click.bar' /* #1 */, wrap_handler(show_06_info));
d3.select("#s-07").on('click.bar', wrap_handler(show_07_info));
// ...
```

(I guess you'll need to do the same for any events you want to handle twice. Some functionality seems to be duplicated between the two scripts.)

custom_jQuery.js handlers look like this:

```
d3.select("#s-10").on('click.foo', function() {
```

Disposing dimension and group on redraw:

```
  if(allPolesPie) {
    allPolesPie.dimension().dispose(); // will dispose group as well
    allPolesPie
      .group(group)
      .dimension(dim)
      .redraw();
  } else {
```

I've tested this in my clone of your repo, but I'll let you apply it to your own code since I think you are leaning on me a bit too much... there are many parts of this which I think you should learn how to diagnose yourself.

[image: proof that i got it to work]

If you continue working with dc.js and d3, you will need to learn how to use the developer tools, especially breakpoints and/or logging, to see what code is getting hit and what the values are.

Comment: I have made the changes in the functions, but do I now need to replace the "dc.renderAll()"s from earlier with "dc.redrawAll()"? I went ahead and did that but now there's a "TypeError: Cannot read property 'classed' of undefined".

Comment: `render` initializes the charts and `redraw` updates them. You need to call `renderAll` the first time, but when switching between data sets you should be able to use `redrawAll` and get animated transitions.

Comment: Also, it seems like the 06 functions are just filtering the data. I don't know what you are trying to do overall, but it might be easier just to have a season dimension which is either `filter(null)` (all), or `filter('2006')` to show just one season. If that's the case, it would save a lot of duplicated code.

Comment: I'm at a loss here. This logic looks right but still not working with the buttons:
~~~~
if(allWinsPie) {
    allWinsPie.redraw();
  } else {
    allWinsPie = dc.pieChart("#wins-pie");
  allWinsPie
    .height(200)
    .width(200)
    //...
    .transitionDuration(1000);

  allWinsPie.render();
  }
~~~~

And then dc.renderAll() removed from the show_all and show_06 functions.

Comment: Don't you still need to set the new data before you redraw?

Comment: I thought I was doing that with the parameters? I can offer up my github page if you'd be so kind as to have a look? https://github.com/AdrianHavengaBennett/f1-data-dashboard

Comment: Hi, @Gordon , I forgot to mention you in the above comment so I'm not sure you've seen it?

Comment: Thanks for the ping; I saw that but got caught up in other things. Hope to take a look today. This is drifting pretty far from a general SO question that will be useful to others, but I may also edit some of your code into the question to make it self-contained.

Comment: `.dimension(dim).group(group)` sets the new data to the chart. You need to do that before you redraw. Currently you are creating the new dimension and new group and then doing nothing with them. Also I'll reiterate that you don't need to copy and paste so much - you could just filter on the season.

Comment: Cool dashboard btw! Thanks for the link.

Comment: Okay, I "versioned" both the question and answer and spelled out my comment as the (hopefully) final answer. If this works for you, please click the green checkmark to accept the answer. Otherwise, I'm glad to iterate further.

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback, really appreciate that. And your patience in this matter has been amazing (wish I could reciprocate). However, your changes have not done the trick. I'm starting to wonder if this is even possible, what I'm asking. Is there even a precedent? I can't find one ... I have pushed all changes to my git for you to look at, should you wish to.

Comment: It is a button that filters. It is way more than possible.

Comment: The buttons aren't connected to the code because the identifiers don't match. You use dashes for IDs whereas the code assumes underscores. The code in `custom_jQuery.js` is getting fired when the buttons are pressed, not the code in `script.js`.

Comment: hmm, can’t believe I missed that. Have fixed that, thanks, but sad to report it still hasn’t done the trick. Is it possible that the jQuery event listeners are clashing with the Javascript ones?

Comment: Yeah, that's one of a few problems. I got it working in a fork of your repo, and documented the changes I needed to make above.

Comment: Did you get it to work? [My fork is here[(https://github.com/gordonwoodhull/f1-data-dashboard) if it helps.

Comment: I did, yes. Decided to merge the script files in the end for simplicity. Also added elasticX (and Y) to the bar charts as the total points and amount of races was changing, but not visually. All is working as it should, thanks heaps for the assistance. Did you manage to get all_info to redraw once clicked?

Comment: Great. I didn't try the All button because I figured it should be very similar to the others. I was just doing a proof of concept. Are you still having trouble with that one?

Comment: Yeah. Seems like it might have something to do with the initial call to all_info because if I remove it, which subsequently loads no info to the page, the event listener call works. However, none of the other buttons then work.

Comment: You have separate variables `allWinsPie`, `winsPie`; `allStackedChart`, `stackedChart`, etc, when really each pair of variables refers to the same chart. The logic will get confused when it looks to see if the chart already exists, think that it doesn't, and try to initialize the chart from scratch. Removing the `all*` variables and replacing each with the non-all version seems to fix the problem.

Comment: Oh, right. That works now. The things I've learned from you are so far above what I've learned thus far in my 3 months, max, since starting with js. The course only scratched the surface on D3, DC, and Crossfilter, it seems. I greatly appreciate your patience and will be crediting you in my project for sure. You've helped a lot.

Comment: Most of this is general programming skills. I've been at this for decades, and still learning. Good luck on your journey!

Comment: Thanks, @Gordon . I’m almost positive we’ll run into each other again here on SO. Perhaps one day I could return the favour.